# SQL INSERT INTO SELECT - existing rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join, insert

I have looked around on the other questions but cant seem to find my answer.

When using the insert into select statement my query always creates new rows.

However I want a script that will insert data into a specific row where a condition is met.

For example: I have two tables, orders and Customers:

```
Orders:     
ORDER_Num     
CUSTOMER_ID  
CUSTOMER_NAME       
Order_Value

Customers: 
CUSTOMER_Num  
CUSTOMER_NAME    
Customer_Location
```

I want it so when I enter the Customer_NUM (This is the same as CUSTOMER_ID) I can run a script and it gets the Customer Name and populates the field with the corresponding Name.

I will probably create this as a stored procedure.

May I have the script in basic format ?

Resolved:

```
update ORDERS
set ORDERS.CUSTOMER_NAME = Customers.CUSTOMER_NAME
from orders
join Customers
on ORDERS.CUSTOMER_ID = Customers.CUSTOMER_Num
```

Comment: Intersted by you have CUSTOMER_NAME in both tables. It makes more sense to me to only have the CUSTOMER_NAME in the Customers table.

Comment: if i understand correctly, enter the customer_id and then display the customer_name..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must use `UPDATE` statement when you want to update some field of exisitng row. `INSERT` statement when you want to create a new row.

I try to explain better with some examples:

You want to add a new customer

```
INSERT INTO customer (field_name) VALUES (values_to_put_in_fields)
```

We can suppose in your INSERT you don't know the document number of customer, but you know after some time.

So, you can write an `UPDATE` statement in this way

```
UPDATE customer 
   SET document_no = 'mydoc' 
 WHERE customer_id = 'id_of_your_customer'
```

If it's OK tell me, if I don't understand your answer tell me too ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting more advanced, there is the `MERGE` statement: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

If you are not a sql super-wiz then stick with the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` ... I usually do.